# How to Call this C# Class (PropertyRepository class) Method

Tags: c#, interface, repository

I'm studying this pattern and I want to execute a method but I don't know how to call it since of these parameterized constructors seem so complex to me. The code that I am following is composed of two interfaces and two classes. below is the sample code. Please help me how to call the "TestMethod()". If possible someone can help me with the following goals.

1. Call the "TestMethod()".
2. Explain this pattern and its importance. (If simplicity is better please help how to simplify them).
3. Explain why the constructors are parameterized. (If simplicity is better please help how to simplify them).

**Console Application**

```
 class Program
    {
        private static IPropertyService _property;
        public Program(IPropertyService property)
        {
            _property = property;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter something...");
            _property.TestMethod(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public interface IPropertyService
        {
            string TestMethod(string strParam);
        }

        private class PropertyService : IPropertyService
        {
            private readonly IPropertyRepository _propertyRepository;

            public PropertyService(IPropertyRepository propertyRepository)
            {
                _propertyRepository = propertyRepository;
            }
            public string TestMethod(string strParam)
            {
                return _propertyRepository.TestMethod(strParam);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IPropertyRepository
    {
        string TestMethod(string strParam);
    }
    public class PropertyRepository : IPropertyRepository
    {
        public string TestMethod(string strParam)
        {
            return string.Format("You have entered: {0}", strParam);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program is your entry point class. Don't make it parameterized constructor. It will not working.

```
public Program(IPropertyService property)
```

You don't need to define `IPropertyService` as private static method. Declare it locally inside Main method and it will ok.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter something...");
    IPropertyService _property = //to be added;
    _property.TestMethod(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now let's talk about the `//to be added` section.

In this case, the simplest solution so far is to use [Abstract Factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/). Example for manual coded:

```
public class PropertyServiceFactory{
  public IPropertyService Create(){
    IPropertyRepository repository = new PropertyRepository();
    PropertyService service = new PropertyService(repository);
    return service; 
  }
}
```

The implementation:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter something...");
PropertyServiceFactory factory = new PropertyServiceFactory();
IPropertyService _property = factory.Create();
_property.TestMethod(Console.ReadLine());
```

However in case you want to break dependency between PropertyServiceFactory and PropertyRepository, modify your factory to:

```
public class PropertyServiceFactory{
  private readonly IPropertyRepository _repository;
  public PropertyServiceFactory(IPropertyRepository repository){
    _repository = repository
  }
  public IPropertyService Create(){
    PropertyService service = new PropertyService(_repository);
    return service; 
  }
}
```

With this you have decoupled the PropertyServiceFactory and PropertyRepository. The implementation are:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter something...");
IPropertyRepository repository = new PropertyRepository();
PropertyServiceFactory factory = new PropertyServiceFactory(repository);
IPropertyService _property = factory.Create();
_property.TestMethod(Console.ReadLine());
```

Credits to Mark Seemann